# How do you pivot some columns into rows using sql or t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Here is the table

```
Income|Expenses|Other|Department|Date

 2k   |      4k|  .5k|Marketing |2014-05-28
 52k  |      7k|  .1k|Sales     |2014-04-01
```

Result

```
Description|Value|Department|Date

 Income    |   2k|Marketing |2014-05-28
 Expenses  |   4k|Marketing |2014-05-28
 Other     |  .5k|Marketing |2014-05-28
 Income    |  52k|Sales     |2014-04-01
 Expenses  |   7k|Sales     |2014-04-01
 Other     |  .1k|Sales     |2014-04-01
```

Actually, I can use SELECT + UNION to get the result but the requirement is to use Pivot.

How to get this result using PIVOT function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `UNPIVOT`

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE (Income VARCHAR(20), Expenses VARCHAR(20), Other VARCHAR(20), Department VARCHAR(20), Date [Date])
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
('2k ', '4k','.5k','Marketing','2014-05-28'),
('52k', '7k','.1k','Sales    ','2014-04-01')

SELECT Description, Value, Department, Date 
FROM @SampleData T
UNPIVOT ([Value] FOR [Description] IN ([Income], [Expenses], [Other])) AS UNPVT
```

Result:

```
Description       Value                Department           Date
----------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
Income            2k                   Marketing            2014-05-28
Expenses          4k                   Marketing            2014-05-28
Other             .5k                  Marketing            2014-05-28
Income            52k                  Sales                2014-04-01
Expenses          7k                   Sales                2014-04-01
Other             .1k                  Sales                2014-04-01
```

Comment: Thanks this one is very fast... but what if some [value] of  income, expenses or other are NULL? It doesn't take lines with null values. how do you solve this?

Comment: You're welcome! UNPIVOT is not taken into account null values. You need to convert null values to space or something before using with unpivot.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot your values via a Cross Apply

```
Select B.*
      ,A.Department
      ,A.Date
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Income'  ,Income  )
                     ,('Expences',Expenses)
                     ,('Other'   ,Other   )
             ) B(Description,Value)
```

Comment: Excellent answer but it takes 4 sec on a 500k rows table. I'll try to optimize this later

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select tt.Description, tt.Value, t.Department, t.Date
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('Income', Income), ('Expenses', Expenses), ('Other', Other) 
     ) tt(Description, Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just for fun**, here is a little technique to "dynamically" unpivot your data without Dynamic SQL or declaring all the columns.

**Example**

```
Select Description = B.[Key]
      ,B.Value
      ,A.Department
      ,A.Date
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select [Key]
                      ,Value
               From OpenJson( ( Select A.* for JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper)   )  
               Where [Key] not in ('Department','Date')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Description Value   Department  Date
Income      2k      Marketing   2014-05-28
Expenses    4k      Marketing   2014-05-28
Other       .5k     Marketing   2014-05-28
Income      52k     Sales       2014-04-01
Expenses    7k      Sales       2014-04-01
Other       .1k     Sales       2014-04-01
```